# calculating the curl of u and v wind components in satellite data - Python

Tags: python, numpy, vector, signal-processing, weather

I am not sure how to take derivatives of the u and v components of the wind in satellite data. I thought I could use numpy.gradient in this way:

```
    from netCDF4 import Dataset      
    import numpy as np      
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

    GridSat = Dataset('analysis_20040713_v11l30flk.nc4','r',format='NETCDF4')
    missing_data = -9999.0
    lat = GridSat.variables['lat']   
    lat = lat[:]     
    lat[np.where(lat==missing_data)] = np.nan  
    lat[np.where(lat > 90.0)] = np.nan     

    lon = GridSat.variables['lon']   
    lon = lon[:]                
    lon[np.where(lon==missing_data)] = np.nan


    uwind_data = GridSat.variables['uwnd']  
    uwind = GridSat.variables['uwnd'][:]
    uwind_sf = uwind_data.scale_factor   
    uwind_ao = uwind_data.add_offset
    miss_uwind = uwind_data.missing_value

    uwind[np.where(uwind==miss_uwind)] = np.nan    


    vwind_data = GridSat.variables['vwnd']  
    vwind = GridSat.variables['vwnd'][:]
    vwind_sf = vwind_data.scale_factor    
    vwind_ao = vwind_data.add_offset
    miss_vwind = vwind_data.missing_value

    vwind[np.where(vwind==miss_vwind)] = np.nan  


    uwind = uwind[2,:,:]
    vwind = vwind[2,:,:]  

    dx = 28400.0 # meters calculated from the 0.25 degree spatial gridding 
    dy = 28400.0 # meters calculated from the 0.25 degree spatial gridding 

    dv_dx, dv_dy = np.gradient(vwind, [dx,dy])
    du_dx, du_dy = np.gradient(uwind, [dx,dy])


    File "<ipython-input-229-c6a5d5b09224>", line 1, in <module>
     np.gradient(vwind, [dx,dy])

    File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nump/lib/function_base.py", line 1040, in gradient
out /= dx[axis]

    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (628,1440) (2,) (628,1440)
```

Honestly, I am not sure how to calculate central differences of satellite data with (0.25x0.25) degree spacing. I dont think my dx and dy are correct either. I would really appreciate if someone had a good idea on approaching these types of calculations in satellite data. Thank you!!

Comment: This is an interesting question. Calculating the curl of a set of discrete points is somewhat different than the calculation over a continuous field. There are a few ways to go about it: 1) If you want a 'smoother' data output or have noisy input information, then taking the average of the cross products of the vector at (i,j) and the eight(or more) surrounding grid squares weighted by distance from the grid square of interest. 2) The simplest method is to use the first method on just the 4 adjacent squares, but you'll have less resolution in diagonal features.

Comment: 3) There are numerical methods that can be used to take the discrete data and map it as a nth order continuous function, which would be the 'best' way, but also by far the most computationally intensive and complicated to implement.

Comment: The documentation for `numpy.gradient` is a bit dodgy on this aspect, but the right way of calling it is: `gradient(vwind, dx, dy)`. I.e. the function signature is `gradient(f, *varargs, **kwargs)`, where `varargs` is a list that is expanded by the "splat" or "unpack" operator.

Comment: I removed the `curl` tag because that refers to a Linux tool, not the mathematical concept.

Answer (score 1):

As `@moarningsun` commented, changing how you call `np.gradient` should correct the `ValueError`

```
dv_dx, dv_dy = np.gradient(vwind, dx,dy)
du_dx, du_dy = np.gradient(uwind, dx,dy)
```

How you got `vwind` from the file is not particularly important, especially since we don't have access to that file.  The shape of `vwind` would have been useful, though we can guess that from the error message.  The reference in the error to a `(2,)` array is to `[dx,dy]`.  When you get `broadcasting` errors, check the shapes of the various arguments.

`np.gradient` code is straight forward, only complicated by the fact that it can handle 1, 2, 3d and higher data.  Basically it doing calculations like

```
(z[:,2:]-z[:,:-2])/2
(z[2:,:]-z[:-2,:])/2
```

for the inner values, and 1 item steps for the boundary values.

I'll leave the question of deriving a `curl` from the gradients (or not) to others.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there is the issue of having to implement a discrete curl operator of some kind. This is presumably a routine concern in atmospheric physics so you could check a textbook on that.

Another approach might be to fit a spline to the data so that you can use continuous operations. For example

```
bspl = scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,s=0)
```

`s` here is a smoothing factor which you should play with; if the data are very precise `s=0` gives best results; if they have substantial scatter you will want some smoothing.Now you can compute the curl directly:

```
curl = bspl.integral(x0,x1,y0,y1) / ((x1-x0)*(y1-y0))
```

EDIT:
The above expression does not give the curl, but the basic idea is sound.

Answer (score -1):

The code below can be ran on Matlab wind dataset, the file wind.mat is in

http://bioinformatics.intec.ugent.be/MotifSuite/INCLUSive_for_users/CPU_64/Matlab_Compiler_Runtime/v79/toolbox/matlab/demos/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import scipy.io as sio

def curl(x,y,z,u,v,w):
    dx = x[0,:,0]
    dy = y[:,0,0]
    dz = z[0,0,:]

    dummy, dFx_dy, dFx_dz = np.gradient (u, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])
    dFy_dx, dummy, dFy_dz = np.gradient (v, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])
    dFz_dx, dFz_dy, dummy = np.gradient (w, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])

    rot_x = dFz_dy - dFy_dz
    rot_y = dFx_dz - dFz_dx
    rot_z = dFy_dx - dFx_dy

    l = np.sqrt(np.power(u,2.0) + np.power(v,2.0) + np.power(w,2.0));

    m1 = np.multiply(rot_x,u)
    m2 = np.multiply(rot_y,v)
    m3 = np.multiply(rot_z,w)

    tmp1 = (m1 + m2 + m3)
    tmp2 = np.multiply(l,2.0)

    av = np.divide(tmp1, tmp2)

    return rot_x, rot_y, rot_z, av

mat = sio.loadmat('wind.mat')
x = mat['x']; y = mat['y']; z = mat['z']
u = mat['u']; v = mat['v']; w = mat['w']

rot_x, rot_y, rot_z, av = curl(x,y,z,u,v,w)


# plot a small area of the wind
i=5;j=7;k=8;S = 3
x1 = x[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S]; 
y1 = y[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S]; 
z1 = z[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S];
u1 = u[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S]; 
v1 = v[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S]; 
w1 = w[i-S:i+S, j-S:j+S, k-S:k+S];

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(elev=47, azim=-145)

ax.quiver(x1, y1, z1, u1, v1, w1, length=0.05, color = 'black')

i=5;j=7;k=8;
x0=x[i,j,k]
y0=y[i,j,k]
z0=z[i,j,k]
cx0=rot_x[i,j,k]
cy0=rot_y[i,j,k]
cz0=rot_z[i,j,k]
ax.quiver(x0, y0, z0, 0, cy0, cz0, length=1.0, color = 'blue')

plt.show()
```